# Retrieving a user's phone number from GSuite oauth?

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace

We're using our staff users on GSuite to authenticate with our management system which we are restricting to our hosted domain.

We'd like to be able to grab our staff's phone number from their company Google account so we don't have to build separate CRUD to allow us to manage their phone number.

Users are authenticated with the 'email' & 'profile' scopes.

Is it possible to retrieve the user's phone number in addition to their name, email, image?

Answer (score 2):

See all the Google [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). 
There is a scope for Phone#
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read  View your phone numbers

Comment: Thanks, you're correct that's the scope to access the data but it doesn't automatically get returned in the oauth response. I'd ideally like to avoid a separate call to gAPI to get the phone, just like we get wth name, email & image.